# error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type 'const char[]'

Tags: c++

I'm getting tons of errors on my private class members. Please help me work through them.

error: a brace-enclosed initializer is not allowed here before '{' token

error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type 'const char []'

error: 'LETTERS_ARR' has not been declared

error: 'LETTERS_ARR' has not been declared

error: expected ',' or '...' before '+' token

error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member 'SNTNC_SMLRTY_THRSHLD_DEFAULT'

error: making 'SNTNC_SMLRTY_THRSHLD_DEFAULT' static**

```
private:
    std::vector<std::string> files_vec; 
    std::vector<std::string> get_file_sntncs(std::fstream&);
    std::vector<std::string> get_sntnc_wrds(const std::string&);
    double sntnc_smlrty_qtnt(std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<std::string>);
    static const char LETTERS_ARR[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'."};
    static const std::set<char> LETTERS_SET(LETTERS_ARR, LETTERS_ARR + sizeof(LETTERS_ARR)/sizeof(char));
    double sntnc_smlrty_thrshld; 
    static const double SNTNC_SMLRTY_THRSHLD_DEFAULT = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you are not allowed to supply in-class initializers for static members of non-integral non-enum type. For such members the initializer is supplied at the point of definition, not at the point of declaration.

Alternatively, as @juanchopanza noted in the comments, you can declare your static members as `constexpr` instead of `const` (assuming you are using a C++11 compiler), which will permit you to supply in-class initializers for such members just like you do in your original code.

Comment: Unless they are `constexpr`, IIRC.